# Fixed top navigation element and anchors

Tags: html, css

With the following CSS, anchor links end up being hidden by the navigation bar.

What solution would you proposed to have the anchor link text being shown just under it?

```
/* style and size the navigation bar */
table.navigation#top
{
  position: fixed;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Put your navigation bar inside of a container that has `padding-top` that matches the height of your navigation bar.

You should also be able to `position: relative` your links give them a `top` that matches the height of your navigation bar.

Comment: I would use javascript to get the height of the navigation bar and set that value as the `padding-top` of the containing element.

Answer (score 1):

You can fix the navbar in place with `position:fixed` and `top:0` (as you're already doing), and set its `height` to a given value, and then apply the same value to the `padding-top` property of each of the target anchors.

This way, when the navigation links are clicked on, the top of the anchor elements will move to the top of the browser's viewport, and while they will be partially covered by the navigation bar (due to `z-index:1` set in the navbar), this covered part will be the padding area which won't have any content, and will typically be invisible (unless borders or background colors are added). The content will thus correctly start right after the navbar.

Here's example code:

- css:

  ```
  #navbar
  {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    height: 1em;
    margin: 0;
  }

  .heading
  {
    padding-top: 1em; 
  }
  ```
- html:

  ```
  <div id="content">
    <h2 id="one" class="heading">Section 1</h2>
    ...
    <h2 id="two" class="heading">Section 2</h2>
    ...
    <h2 id="three" class="heading">Section 3</h2>
    ...
  </div>
  <div id="navbar">
    <a href="#one">Section 1</a>
    <a href="#two">Section 2</a>
    <a href="#three">Section 3</a>
  </div>
  ```

Of course, this doesn't solve the problem of a dynamic navbar height, but Bryan's suggestion to use JavaScript for that is probably the easiest (only?) way to implement this.

ps - Keep in mind that the if the id'd element has `display:block` or `display:inline-block`, the padding will have an effect on the page layout, which might not be desirable.

Answer (score 1):

Look in [here](http://nicolasgallagher.com/jump-links-and-viewport-positioning/demo/#method-D), method D solves my the problem. The css is basically:

```
#method-D {
    border-top:50px solid transparent;
    margin-top:-50px;
    -webkit-background-clip:padding-box;
    -moz-background-clip:padding;
    background-clip:padding-box;
}
```

I'm using a dynamical navbar that is fixed to the top just when it's going to be hidden.